# Arrays/pointers in C: copying without knowing underlying type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Let's say I've got a `unsigned char` pointer (`uchar*` from now on) to the beginning of an array of type `T` different from `uchar`. Knowing the size of this array and that it is continuous (created using `malloc`), is it possible to copy it to another array without knowing the type `T`? How can I access it byte per byte?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the size of the array in bytes or in number of elements?

Comment: How come you don't know the type `T`? Sounds to me like you're mixing C and C++, which is rarely a good idea.

Comment: For reasons way too long to explain, I can't use a template class. My solution then was to store the data I need in this 'generic' pointer. But because of that I can't know the real type.

Comment: why just casting your `uchar*` to `T*` isn't enough? If you know the size of the array and the size of `T` (as you say) than you know the number of elements in the array, so you are on the safe side

Comment: @dav: How can you cast to `T*` without knowing `T`?

Comment: @Davka: how would I access the element? Would it be `*((T*)(data + 5))` [for instance to access the element of index 5]?

Comment: @Renan: No, it would be `((T*)data)[5]`. But of course that only works if you know the type `T`. Do you?

Comment: @Fred: correct, it's knowing the size of T vs. knowing T confused me

Comment: @Renan: I'd `T* t = reinterpret_cast<T*>(data); t[5];`, but as @Fred remarked, you must know the `T`

Comment: How come the question has "C" in the title but is tagged "C++"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a shallow copy of everything with a simple `memcpy` or `memmove`, but you better be sure that the array elements are no class objects that contain any pointers. Or more precisely, make sure they are [PODs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

Comment: Totally wrong if you do not know the array size you cannot use memcpy or memmove.

Comment: @VGE: the OP says the array size is known.

Comment: @VGE: "Knowing the size of this array and that it is continuous" -- taken verbatim from the OP.

Comment: @VGE But hasn't Renan mentioned that array size is known?

Comment: @VGE: But I do know the array size
@Xeo: If I know the size of each element, is it possible to access them individually?

Comment: It is not enough you have to know the size of T. and you cannot know size of T without knowing T. memory size = sizeof(T) * #items.

Comment: @Renan: What exactly do you mean by "access" the element? If you don't even know the type `T`, what do you want to do with the element?

Comment: @VGE: If you know the size of the array, simply `memcpy`ing each byte will achieve what the OP is asking for. `memcpy` doesn't need to know the correct amount of elements since we're talking about bytes anyways.

Comment: @Renan, unless your are just copying bytes around, you'd need to know the type `T` to do anything useful with it.

Comment: They can be PODs and still contain pointers to itself or to other objects in the array. Using memcpy will break in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
T foo; // your given arbitrary object
T bar; // target

unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&foo);  // type-punned
unsigned char * q = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&bar);  // ditto

memcpy(q, p, sizeof(T)); // copy byte-wise
```

If `T` has non-trivial properties (custom constructors, pointers to heap variables, etc.), this has lots of potential to cause trouble, but you can certainly access the raw data via those pointers. (Doing this in general may be fun for instance if you want to look at the binary representation of a `double`  or something like that, but in production code this should rarely come up.)

If your original object is `T foo[N]`, use the size `sizeof(T) * N`.

*Edit:* Do you mean that you want this to work for an *arbitrary* type or for an *unknown* type? If you don't know the size of `T` (e.g. if you are *only* handed the pointer), then of course you cannot do it because you don't know how much memory is occupied. There are no "field delimiters" or anything like that stored in memory that you could inspect at runtime.

Comment: Someone keeps up- and down-voting, care to comment why?